# SSRS 2008r2 Show data in Table and Charts based on x number of rows at a time

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I have a report which contains a table and a number of charts.

Is it possible to show x number of rows on each page and just the data in those rows in the charts?

Comment: So you want to specify, for instance, 10 records in the table on each page and have the chart only show the records on that page?

Comment: Put everything into a matrix and group the entire thing by sets of rows.  Put page breaks after each instance of the group.  It won't be easy, but it's possible.

Comment: That's right @JC , that's what I'm after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a parent row group, grouping on `=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) \ 10`. Add a footer row to that group. Put your chart in that footer row. Set that group to pagebreak between.

`=(RowNumber(Nothing) - 1) \ 10` returns 0 for the first 10 items, 1 for the next 10, etc. Grouping on that with pagebreaks will give you pages of 10 records. Charts in the group footer cells will use just those 10 rows (by default).

Comment: Thanks @JC, that's works well.  I have multiple charts.  Can you add multiple charts to the footer row?

Comment: You just add additional rows to the footer, Doh!

Comment: any idea why I'm getting a page break in the middle of a group when I've set the KeepTogether property to True?